# Can't get GUI login screen on Debian Jessie [after upgrade from Wheezy]

Tags: debian, x11, gdm3

Upon boot GDM3 is correctly started but hangs at the splash screen and no GUI login box appears. The only way to log into the system and graphical interface is following these steps:

1. `CTRL+ALT+F1`
2. logging in
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop && startx`

What could be broken?

I tried `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` to no avail...
Also, `grep EE etc/X11/xorg.conf` doesn't return any error.

Comment: Could you post you logs ? `tail -n 30 /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE

I found a workaround after reading these bug reports: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785782 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=724731

In my case the workaround was installing lightdm as display manager.
`sudo aptitude install lightdm`
This also prompts you to choose it as default display manager.

However this still doesn't solve the apparent bug in gdm3...